# How to fake an incoming call in android

Tags: android, android-intent, adb

I want to fake a call from 1111111111 to my android device. I ran this command inside android terminal.
`am start -a android.intent.action.CALL tel:111111111`
It made an call. But i could not find how to receive a fake call. For example i want to fake a call from 1111111111. I tried this command for receiving fake call.
`am broadcast -a android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE --es state "RINGING" --es incoming_number "1112223333"`
It says `broadcast completed : result=0` but i don't get any call or see any call logs. Anybody knows what the problem here?